# Why adding documents to gensim Dictionary gets slow when reaching 2 million words?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, gensim

I noticed that when adding documents to a gensim Dictionary, execution time jumps from 0.2s to more than 6s when reaching 2 million words.

The code below is a quick example. I loop through int and add the number to the dictionary at each iteraion.

```
from gensim import corpora
import time



dict_transcript = corpora.Dictionary()


for i in range(1,10000000):

    start_time = time.time()

    doc = [str(i)]

    dict_transcript.add_documents([doc])

    print("Iter "+str(i)+" done in " + str(time.time() - start_time) + ' w/ '+str(len(doc)) + ' words and dico size ' +
          str(len(dict_transcript)))
```

I do get the following output when reaching 2 million words:

```
Iter 1999999 done in 0.0 w/ 1 words and dico size 1999999
Iter 2000000 done in 0.0 w/ 1 words and dico size 2000000
Iter 2000001 done in 0.0 w/ 1 words and dico size 2000001
Iter 2000002 done in 7.940511226654053 w/ 1 words and dico size 2000001
```

Is there any reason why? And does anyone know how to bypass that problem?
I'm using this dictionary on a big corpus that I tokenize into bigrams so I'm expecting the dictionary to be a few million rows.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [gensim documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html):

> *class* `gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary(documents=None, prune_at=2000000)`
>
> **prune_at** (int, optional) – Total number of unique words. Dictionary will keep not more than prune_at words.

Set `prune_at=None` or to a suitable integer for your use case.

Comment: How is the prune_at argument working? I mean, how is it affecting the run time? I've been trying different values of prune_at myself, and it's not affecting the dictionary size.